# Displaying an userform multiples times in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble to loop an userform and get data from it.
My code is already properly working whenever I use it for a single use (out of the loop).
The objective is to send data obtained using the ComboBox values (which is done in the Userform code) in a sheet and this has to be done X times (X being defined by the user at the start of the code) but whenever I enter the loop, my userform is only displayed once.
I did see that some people used the vbModeless option but since I didn't notice any change, I thought of it being a hint but didn't find anything close to it that solved my problem.

```
Sub nouveau_controle()
    Dim nbre_controle As Integer
    nbre_controle = InputBox("Entrez le nombre de contrôles à effectuer")
    For j = 1 To nbre_controle Step 1
        Formulaire_nouveau_controle.Show vbModeless
    Next j
End Sub
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a form `vbModeless`, it means 2 things:
(1) you can continue to work with excel while the form is open
(2) your code will immediately continue to run after the `Show`

As the code continues to run, your code hits the `Show`-command without stop. When the user closes it, it is not reopened as the code is already executed completely

The opposite is to open the form `modal` (this is the default). Execution stops at the `Show` command and waits until the form is closed. In that case, you should see you form multiple times. Examples for typical modal forms are `InputBox` or `MsgBox`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was away from computer this two days. So I tried changing the code to modal : it works whenever I fill all ComboBoxs, I also add some situations that were not covered due to some lacking conditions. Thanks for the help and for the explanation, it helped me fix a few other things !